# OnClientClick code preventing validation from working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've added code the the OnClientClick property of an asp.net button and now the validation controls are not working.  When I remove the OnClientClick code the validation works.

How can I get both of them to work?

```
<asp:Button 
ID="btnNext" 
runat="server" 
Text="Save & Continue" 
SkinID="btnContinue" 
OnClick="btnNext_Click"  
OnClientClick="_changesMade=false; return true;" 
ValidationGroup="vgPreMedSchool" Width="176px" />
```

Comment: how come you don't have a runat = server check if this is allowed also "_changesMade=false; return true; can you post the JavaScript code for both OnClientClick= expects javaScript in your case if I am not mistaken

Comment: id do, i think someone edited the question to just show the relevant parts of the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:Button 
ID="btnNext" 
runat="server" 
Text="Save & Continue" 
SkinID="btnContinue" 
OnClick="btnNext_Click"  
OnClientClick="_changesMade=false; return Page_ClientValidate();" 
ValidationGroup="vgPreMedSchool" Width="176px" />
```

**Page_ClientValidate()** is a javascript function that asp.net uses to invoke the page validation.

Comment: Don't forget to include a validation group as an argument to Page_ClientValidate, if you use them (and you should :)

Answer (score 1):

The validator controls work by default on the client end, essentially adding their own functionality to click click events. There are a couple of ways to solving this:

1) Use custom validators and define your own client validation method. That way you can handle both the validation and the additional processing you need.

2) Disable client side validation. This will allow your client side code to function as needed, and the validation will occur during the post back to the server. However, if you are assuming your data is valid in your own client click method, this won't work for you.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can't call both OnClick and OnClientClick Properties.

You can use only 1 Property at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: you can. OnClientClick occurs first before the OnClick which is a server side function.